# MySQL error in php, but not in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I  have an SQL query that I am running inside of PHP that is not working. I tried to run it in phpmyadmin and it worked, but when I run it in php it doesn't work. I am getting this SQL error message:

> SQL ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO dgds(`Name` , `Url`, 'Date') VALUES ('hdhed', 'gdhd', '12 01 2013'' at line 9

My SQL query is this:

```
CREATE TABLE ". $tbname ."
(
Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Name VARCHAR( 255 ) ,
Url VARCHAR( 255 ) ,
Date VARCHAR ( 255 ),
PRIMARY KEY ( Id )
);
INSERT INTO ". $tbname ." (`Name` ,  `Url`, 'Date') VALUES ('". $name ."',  '". $url ."', '". $date ."');
```

Comment: That's 2 queries, not 1. In code, you need to execute them separately.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO dgds(`Name` ,  `Url`, 'Date') VALUES
```

should be

```
INSERT INTO dgds(`Name` ,  `Url`, `Date`) VALUES
```

(mind the backticks vs. the single quotes around `Date`)